# How to use custom class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How to use custom class in Laravel without creating object `new Class()`?

As sample, I have class `Exception` I include this like as:

```
use App\Exception
```

After in custom class `User` I can do:

```
use App\Exception

class User {

    public function check(Exception $e) {
       // 
    }

}
```

Is it right?

Or I need to create object `$e = new Exception()` in constructor?

Whats is difference between these kind of initialization?

Comment: You could use the Service Container.

Comment: if you need to ask "is it right" you probably didn't try it out. Go ahead and try it yourself - come back with the actual problem / error. The snippet doesnt seem wrong at all. However, I'm not sure if you do what you actually want to do. Currently the only thing you have is a function that expects an object of class Exception as first parameter. So yes this is valid. But at some point you will need to create this Exception so that you can pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `App::abort()` for `HttpExceptions`.

> You want to return a non-200 status code back to the user indicating the request was not successful.

For example:

```
abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#http-exceptions) and [this resource](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/202/throwing-httpexceptions)